# Why height of SPAN more than its font-size

Tags: html, css

I don't understand why the height of span element more than its font-size (margin and padding = 0): [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/c0qbc0at/1/)

```
<head>
    <style>
        .analized-element {
            font-size: 20px;
            font-family: "Lucida Console", "Lucida Grande", monospace;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <span class="analized-element">Test message</span>
</body>
```

---

This problem exists **only in Mac**:

```
== analized-element =====
border-size: 0 0 0 0
padding: 0 0 0 0
font-size: 20px
offsetHeight: 23px
=========================
```

How we can see there are 3 extra pixels. The same example **in Windows**:

```
== analized-element =====
border-size: 0 0 0 0
padding: 0 0 0 0
font-size: 20px
offsetHeight: 20px
=========================
```

The height of span equals to its font-size.

Comment: I get `offsetHeight: 20px` on Safari on Mac OS X. Which browser are you using?

Comment: try adding media screen

Comment: It's very strange. I tested it in Chrome, FF and Safari. Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. My colleague got the same results that I have. I can attach screenshot if it's a necessary. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 460px){
    body{
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add
`line-height: 20px` and `display: inline-block` for the `.analized-element` element to fix this issue.

Or `line-height: 1` and `font-size: 20px` for the body element.